Why is this accusative? "Lach über die Witze von der Eule, bitte."
Lach über die Witze von der Eule, bitte.
Why is this not dative?  I know that über can be dative or accusative.  But I understand that if movement is denoted then we use accusative, otherwise it's dative.  Since someone is laughing OVER OR ABOUT something, no movement is denoted so it shouldbe dative.  I wrote this as "über den Witze" since its plural and dative. Duolingo said it's wrong and put the above sentenct Please help to correct my understanding.

Sometimes Duo doesn't explain everything you need to know all at once. They don't want you to go into information overload so they give you a little bit at time. I think this time the question is using information that may be coming later in the course; that kind of thing happens sometimes.

It's important to note, and it's mentioned a bit in another comment, that the movement/direction rule, even when correctly stated, only applies to variable prepositions, aka Wechselpräpositionen, such as "über". The preposition "zu" is always dative and the rule doesn't apply.

When "über" means "about", i.e. introduces a topic (of anything), it requires the accusative.
Du hast eine interessante Frage über die deutsche Sprache [not: der deutschen Sprache] gestellt, allerdings ist die Antwort wirklich so einfach. Es hat wenig Sinn, weiter über dieses Thema [not "diesem Thema"] zu diskutieren, die Präposition funktioniert einfach so.

Your understanding is wrong. It is not about movement. With location prepositions, accusative is used for direction, dative is used for location. The "direction" here is a rather figurative one, though, as über is not a location preposition here in the strict sense of the word. The simpler way to look at it is to say that über etw. (Akk.) lachen is the valence of the verb, and you should memorize it that way.
On a side note, dative plural of der Witz would be den Witzen.

I wouldn't really try and argue along the lines of Wechselpräpositionen here (this leads to confusion as there is no "wechseln" at all involved.) I would simply argue "lachen über etwas" (Acc) is a standing expression.

@tofro - I would call it a prepositional verb, similar to English "laugh at" except for some differences in meaning. (German has "auslachen" which could also be translated as "laugh at" but meant differently.) In my experience you just have to memorize the case for the variable prepositions in prepositional verbs, but it's more often accusative than dative. A good dictionary should include these, for example def. 1a in DWDS. You can tell it's accusative because they say jmdn. instead of jmdm.

This is because it's a phrasal verb. Consider

Er wartet auf den Bus.

That's not about a direction onto the bus and neither about a location on the bus but the bus is the thing waited for. It's a prepositional object, not an adverbial. For prepositional objects of verbs, you have to learn the preposition and the case the verb wants.
And it's the same for

Er lacht über den Witz.

Again, you have to learn the full phrase über etwas(Akk) lachen. With two-way prepositions, default to accusative. That's more common.

Also, someone told your a wrong rule. With two-way prepositions in adverbials, it's not about movement or no movement. Consider

Auf dem Marktplatz zeigt ein Wegweiser auf den Brunnen.

Nothing moves in this example. Yet we have one auf with dative and one auf with accusative. This is because it's not about movement. At all. It's about location vs direction. The signpost points to the standpost. That's a direction. Hence der Brunnen is put into accusative with auf.
Note that this is a general rule in German. You have to tell apart location and direction. In the example above you can replace the second auf with zu:

Auf dem Marktplatz zeigt ein Wegweiser zum Brunnen.

Zu always takes dative, and yet it means a direction. But you can't replace the first auf by zu because that one means a location.
Also, the direction marks the target. Consider

Der Spieler schoss den Ball ins Tor. (Tor is the direction of the action.)
Der Spieler schoss den Ball am Tor vorbei. (Tor isn't the direction of the action.)


I think it is not possible to predict the case with prepositions other than spatial prepositions. In your example, "über" corresponds to English "about" not to "over". So it is just a different preposition – "über" is simply ambiguous.
In talking about space (and, metaphorically, time) there is some amount of system with the "Wechselpräpositionen" (note that not all spatial prepositions belong to them) – but with other prepositions the case form that appears with them simply has to be learnt, it's arbitrary. For example: "mit ihm" (with, governs dative) but "ohne ihn" (without, governs accusative).
By and large, it is not helpful to think that the cases with German prepositions have a meaning in and by themselves. The only exception is the rule (!) that a place preposition which governs dative can always be used as a directional preposition and then governs accusative. (But note that the rule only applies in this restricted way; there are all sorts of other directional prepositions with all sorts of other cases.)

One nitpick, the "über" in this case would be translated as "at"; you wouldn't say you "laughed about" a joke, In some cases you can "laugh over" something as in German, for example: "We spent the evening laughing over the memory of times long ago." This ELSE question has more detail. To "laugh at", "laugh about", and "laugh over" all cover different situations, and of course none of them correspond exactly with the various similar German expressions.

When I said it corresponds to English "about" what I had in mind was the meaning in isolation (a topic or content of something). But you are right, together with a verb, the verb may require different prepositions.

As far as I understand, the "movement/direction/location" rule with Wechselnpräpositionen only works when the sentence is about something "spatial", and not in other cases.
As I understand you are a beginner, I would suggest you to use the following guidelines. They are not 100% bulletproof but they seem to be enough for you to deepen your understanding and make progress:

Präpositionen always with Dativ: aus / bei / mit / nach / seit / von / zu.

Präpositionen always with Akkusativ: durch / für / gegen / ohne / um.

Wechselnpräpositionen:

In a "spatial" sentence: Akkusativ with a direction, Dativ with a location.
In a "temporal" sentence: Dativ with almost all of them. Example: "er wird vor den Meilensteinen des Projekts eintreffen". Exceptions: Akkusativ with "auf" and "über".
In other cases (e.g. "conceptual" sentences): Akkusativ with verbs implying a thinking process, Dativ otherwise. Examples: "er arbeitet an einem Prozess" / "er denkt an einen Prozess" / "ich fokussiere mich auf meine aktuelle Tätigkeit".



